# Error parsing Bootstrap 4 in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: css, node.js, netbeans, bootstrap-4

I am doing a html5/JS application with Nodejs on Netbeans 8.2.
I am doing the welcome page and I would like to use Bootstrap 4. But when I add bootstrap.min.css in my stylesheets folder I have an error, see the image below. 
However when I add the bootstrap.min.css from Bootstrap 3.3.7 I have no issue.

[image: image of error]

Thanks

Comment: Netbeans throws this error, but it doesn't affect anything in fact. After some research, it looks like Netbeans 8.2 is missing the Css3.g file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I managed to fix it by adding the link of [bootsrapCDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) from of [site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/).

Answer (score 0):

You should before you install the packages, enable apache (xampp or apache2) by directing the folder:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/xxx/NetBeansProjects/xxxxx"
<Directory "/home/xxx/NetBeansProjects/xxxxx">
```

---

I use Linux Mint19:

```
ocs@ocsastro ~/NetBeansProjects/ocsastro $ ruby -v && node -v && npm -v && sass --version                                                                                                                                 
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-linux]
v11.3.0
6.4.1
1.15.1 compiled with dart2js 2.1.0
```

In NetBeans the path must be:

```
http://localhost
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trrKw77DXLk&feature=youtu.be

[image]